# How can I display a circle in a 3D plane in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to project a shadow of the sphere on the ground in 3D. Now I am displaying them as spheres but I need to change them with circles. How could I do that?

Comment: The projection (shadow) of a sphere on a plane is an ellipse (except the projection is perpendicular), if the projection is orthographic (directional light). If the light source is a point light things get even more complicated.

Comment: Note that you can create a transformation matrix which actually projects your geoemtry to a flat plane - even in the perspectivic case, so you can simply draw you original sphere geometry.

Comment: I have managed to do that! thanks, the gluDisk option is the key to display a disk as a shadow.